# NodeJs for Embedded device: lighter alternative to express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm looking for a lighter alternative to express.js for build up a simple rest server in embedded device (OpenWRT).

I need few feature that I'm used to inside express.js:

- a way to make rest endpoint with get, post and delete
- a way to parse the incoming request (body-parser in express)
- a way to use a basic-auth middleware

is there any choice?
I tried to make it vanilla javascript but I'm not so experienced and I had problem in the basic auth middleware and in the body parser..

Comment: connect? https://github.com/senchalabs/connect

Comment: connect could be a valid answer, please add it

Answer (score 1):

I've been using [restify](http://mcavage.me/node-restify/) for a while now and it works well for simple REST APIs. Not as full featured as express, but is well documented and supported for most cases.